# useEffect triggered infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add a list of users in a page and when the component mounts, I'm getting the users in an `useEffect` hook. However, if I add the users in the dependency array, the component re-renders infinitely.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('users', users)
    get('api/user/', (res) => {
        setUsers(res.data.data)
    })
}, [users])
```

If I remove it, then this is solved, but then I want to be able to edit one user on the list and have the app re-render automatically, as it would've done with states and classes.

However, if I edit the `users` list with the dependency array being empty, the component doesn't re-render.

Comment: Array of objects will fail the strict equality `users !== res.data.data`

Comment: @adiga but why? How do I specify that I want to re-render only until users is filled and no more?

Comment: You are setting the `users` to a new array, so it is not equal to the previous value and this re-runs the effect, getting again a new array from the response and setting it.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli can I then do an await get inside useState, so it doesn't have an empty value?

Comment: @Radu `empty` value is not a problem here. The problem is in the logic you have used. You specify a dependency which is modified from inside the effect that depends on it. It is by definition an infinite loop. If you do not want to re-fetch the `users` from the DB do not set a dependency at all. When you update a user from your app, do you store it and want to reload the data from the backend? or do you update the `users` state yourself in-app?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I'm updating the `users` state myself in the app. As for the dependencies, not setting a dependency at all is indeed the way to go for not having that infinite loop. But if I'm updating the user, I'm thinking that I should keep a dependency to it changing in order for the app to reload? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: that dependency, is only for that `useEffect`. If your call the `setUsers` with a new array (*the updated one*), the component will re-render as expected. The dependency is there if you want to re-fetch from the DB. If not, then no dependency is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214596/discussion-between-radu-and-gabriele-petrioli).